# Preprocessor and compiler errors in C

Tags: c, string, compiler-construction, c-preprocessor, preprocessor

When I have a syntax error in C, how can I know if it's a preprocessor error or a compiler error?

Let's say I type in this line: `"# include header.h"` (The `"` is part of the line to make it a string literal).

Will the preprocessor have an issue with it or will it be the compiler that will treat it as a string without assigning it to anything?

Comment: You can run preprocessor only with `gcc -E` (if using `gcc`) and see if it has any problems

Comment: It's usually pretty clear from the error message whether it's a preprocessing problem or not, but if you're not sure you can always stop after preprocessing as suggested by Eugene.  That will tell you for sure.

Comment: Why should the compiler treat it as string? String literals are surrounded by `"`. Does the `"` count to the line or just to emphasize the line in this example?

Comment: Sometimes a faulty preprocessor macro results in a later compiler error, but the error is still with the preprocessor code...

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Yes i meant both " are a part of the line

Comment: @ItamarIvri In this case I would say the compiler would treat it as string literal. The only problem is when you use variables, functions etc. from `header.h`. Then you would get errors about undefined references.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Ok thanks

Comment: @TomKarzes I have not heard about the preprocessor errors. Any examples please.

Comment: @P__J__ Usually it's things like not being able to locate a header file, or wrong number of arguments to a macro, or `#else` without `#if`.  There are a number of examples, and they're usually pretty obvious preprocessing problems.

Comment: *"Will the preprocessor have an issue with it or will it be the compiler that will treat it as a string without assigning it to anything?"* - What happened when you tried?

Answer (score 1):

> "*Will the preprocessor have an issue with it or will it be the compiler that will treat it as a string without assigning it to anything?*"

I've tried your example:

```
"#include <stdio.h>"
```

I get the following errors:

For GCC:

> "*error: expected identifier or '(' before string constant*"

For Clang:

> "*error: expected identifier or '('*"

You can see it [here](https://godbolt.org/z/tHsXvo).

Both GCC and Clang treats it as string literal, which is reasonable since character sequences surrounded by `"` are specified as string literals:

> "A character string literal is a sequence of zero or more multibyte characters enclosed in double-quotes,as in `"xyz"`."
> Source: ISO/IEC 9899:2018 (C18), §6.4.5/3.

This issue is one the compiler cares about, not the preprocessor. In general, since macros are expanded before compilation, the incorrectness or failure of preprocessor directives is usually also something the compiler complains about. There is usually no explicit error detection stage for the C preprocessor.

If the assignment would be proper, f.e.:

```
const char* p = "#include <stdio.h>";
```

and you use variables, functions etc. which are declared in `header.h`, you can* get errors about undefined references about these variables/functions, since the compiler/linker can't see/find those declarations.

*Whether you get an error or not is furthermore dependent upon if the definition of that variable/function is visable before its use in the source code or how you link several source files.

---

> "*When I have a syntax error in C, how can I know if it's a preprocessor error or a compiler error?*"

As said above, there are no real preprocessor errors, the compiler covers these issues. The preprocessor doesn't really analyze for errors, it is just expanding. Usually it is very clear if an error belongs to a macro or not, even though the compiler evaluates the syntactical issues.

As said in the comments already by Eugene, you can take a look at the macro expanded version of your code when using the `-E` option for GCC and test if the expansions were expanded successfully/as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Typically compiler output doesn't distinguish "pre-processor errors" from "compiler errors", as these aren't really standardized terms.

What's called "pre-processing" is often the process of forming pre-processor tokens, followed by resolving all includes, pragmas and macros. In the C standard, this "pre-processing" *roughly* corresponds to "translation phases" 3 and 4:

> 3. The source file is decomposed into preprocessing tokens and sequences of
>    white-space characters (including comments). A source file shall not end in a
>    partial preprocessing token or in a partial comment. Each comment is replaced by
>    one space character. New-line characters are retained. Whether each nonempty
>    sequence of white-space characters other than new-line is retained or replaced by
>    one space character is implementation-defined.

> 4. Preprocessing directives are executed, macro invocations are expanded, and
>    _Pragma unary operator expressions are executed. If a character sequence that
>    matches the syntax of a universal character name is produced by token
>    concatenation (6.10.3.3), the behavior is undefined. A #include preprocessing
>    directive causes the named header or source file to be processed from phase 1
>    through phase 4, recursively. All preprocessing directives are then deleted.

The compiler will not obviously complain about finding a valid string literal `"# include header.h"` in either of the above phases - a string literal is a valid pre-processor token. What you call "pre-processor errors" is probably errors that occur in any of the above phases.

(This is a simplified explanation, there's lots of other mildly interesting stuff happening as well, like trigraph and newline \  replacement etc.)

But in this case, I think the compiler will complain in phase 7, emphasis mine:

> 7. White-space characters separating tokens are no longer significant. Each
>    preprocessing token is converted into a token. **The resulting tokens are
>    syntactically and semantically analyzed** and translated as a translation unit.